# Convert residence permit to work permit in Italy

Tags: italy, work-permit

I have a long-stay student visa in Italy (D1 type) and I'm doing my master's (The first year is almost over). I got a full-time job offer, but I don't know how to convert my permit to a working permit, and the company seems unsure of the process. Has anyone been through a similar experience? What should be the steps, if it's possible?

Comment: "the company seems unsure of the process". If the company really wants to hire you, tell them to figure this out. There are many potential legal pitfalls.

Comment: @Rick
I didn't know about Expats, seems more suitable there, thanks.